# Hola, tengo un problema con el método put para arreglo de objetos proveniente de la api

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, core

[image]

[image]
Es un formulario que me toma los datos y al modificarlos y dar submit me provoca ese error.
ese es el método que estoy utilizando. Ese mismo método me sirvió para el post y delete.
Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor , ya he intentado cambiando el código y agregando en la url de la api =/json/response

Comment: El error 404 te indica que no encuentra el endpoint que estas especificando. Revisa que este correcto

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude solucionar, únicamente había que desactivar y activar el bóton de put en la mock api

Comment: seria ideal que quitaras la imagen del método editarCurso y colocaras el código

Answer (score 0):

capas primero deberias implementar rxjs y crear un observable para enviar el curso con  put, me hace un poco de ruido como esta implementado el catch error. aglo asi:

```
import {Observer} from 'rxjs'

const observer:Observer<Inscripciones> ={   
next: value => console.log('next',value),
error: error => console.log('error,error),
complete:() =>(console.log('completado))


} ;
    
editarCurso(curso:Inscripciones){
  this.http.put<Inscripciones> 
   (`https://6361713367d3b7a0a6c6d7c9.mockapi.io/api/${curso.id}`, 
   curso).pipe().suscribe(observer)
 }
```